# Does IPTable parameter order affect performance?

Tags: optimization, firewall, iptables

Will the following iptable rule

```
iptables -I FORWARD -p tcp -m set --match-set HUUUGE_SET dst --dport 80 -j REJECT
```

be less efficient than this one

```
iptables -I FORWARD -p tcp --dport 80 -m set --match-set HUUUGE_SET dst -j REJECT
```

for a packet with dport != 80.

In other words, is the order in which you specify the parameters the same order in which they're checked or does iptables have some kind of predetermined/optimized parameter checking order.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK, `iptables`'s parameters will be marshaled into a struct to be fed into the `netfilter` kernel module, so order of parameters totally does not affect performance.

Here's a test:

```
# iptables -N test
# iptables -A test -p tcp --dport 80 -s 10.0.0.1 -j DROP
# iptables -A test -p tcp -s 10.0.0.2 --dport 80 -j DROP
# iptables-save | grep test
:test - [0:0]
-A test -s 10.0.0.1/32 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 80 -j DROP
-A test -s 10.0.0.2/32 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 80 -j DROP
#
```

As you can see, whatever order you type the match parameters, `iptables-save` (which dumps the netfilter ruleset currently active in memory) 'canonicalize' the order.